# Rotate photo via python

Tags: python

I have a photo on my disk and I want to rotate it clockwise in 90 degrees. I'm trying to use PIllow as described here:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html#geometrical-transforms

```
pill_img = Image.open(abs_img_src)
pill_img.rotate(90)
```

But nothing changes. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it returns a new image, so you'll want something like

```
from PIL import Image

abs_img_src = 'test.png'

pill_img = Image.open(abs_img_src)
pill.show()

rotated_img = pill_img.rotate(90)
rotated_img.show()
```

If we let our 'test.png' be the Python logo

[image: Python Logo]

```
pill.show()
```

will output

[image: Python Logo using pillow]

```
rotated_img = pill_img.rotate(90)
rotated_img.show()
```

will result in

[image: Python Logo rotated with pillow]

Just to double check, let's now call `im.show()` after the `im.rotate(90)`:

[image: enter code here]

Sure enough, we get the result we expected -- i.e., `im.rotate` does not mutate `im`, but rather it returns a new rotated `Image`.

Comment: so I have to save rotated photo on disk? rotated_img.save(abs_img_src) ?

Comment: @ИгорьОлешко -- Correct. You'll want to save with `rotated_img.save("rotated-" + abs_img_src)` or some such.